# Import JSON file in Elasticsearch

Tags: json, curl

I am newbie for ELK Stack . I need help on importing JSON file in elasticsearch. This is the code that I'm using bellow:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/cus2 -d '
{
"mappings" : {
"_default_" : {
"properties" : {
“mem_id” : { "type" : "integer" },
“username” : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
“password” : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
“fname” : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
“lname” : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
“mname” : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
“address1” : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
“address2” : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
“city” : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
“state” : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }, 
“country” : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
“postal” : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
“contact” : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
“phone2” : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
“email” : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
}
}
}
}
';
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @cus2.json
```

and I got this *error*:

```
{"error":"ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;]","status":500}
```